# Problem receiving join requests and connection status from LoraWAN gateway inside AWS IOT Core LPWAN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iot, lorawan

I'm using AWS IOT Core to receive LoraWAN packets with a RAK7289 LoraWAN gateway.

I was able to configure the gateway, the device, the device profile and the device destination through an MQTT topic and I'm receiving messages from the device.

But when I tried to configure the IAM policy to allow the join requests and connection status to pass over MQTT, AWS says that no permissions are granted:

[image: This policy does not grant any permissions. To grant access, policies must have an action that has an applicable resource or condition.]

Even though I'm using the policy indicated by AWS:

[image]

Has anyone solved this type of issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest to grant the policy greater access to see if it works as you intend (add * to resource / action). If it works then gradually reduce the level of access until you find out what you need. I had a similar issue with IoT policies and this was the way I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

After reaching for AWS Support, they sent a fixed the policy, the correct one is:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:Receive",
                "iot:Subscribe"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<account>:topicfilter/$aws/iotwireless/events/join/*",
                "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<account>:topicfilter/$aws/iotwireless/events/connection_status/*",
                "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<account>:topicfilter/$aws/iotwireless/events/device_registration_state/*",
                "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<account>:topicfilter/$aws/iotwireless/events/proximity/*",
                "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<account>:topicfilter/$aws/iotwireless/events/message_delivery_status/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The AWS documentation is still showing the wrong policy, but according to them, it will be fixed.